# How can I colored Some Values Based on Conditions in Pandas Live Streaming DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, background-color, styling

I'm Printing Live Streaming DataFrame with the Help of Streamz Module, Now I want to Check the Condition of `Df.Percentage` is `Less the 0` then colored should be Red, and if it is greater then 0 then show blue color in each rows.
[image]

This is my Dataframe with Code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from streamz.dataframe import PeriodicDataFrame
import time


def random_datapoint(**kwargs):
    read = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\krishna gupta\Desktop\live_data_output_file.csv')
    read = read.sort_values('Percentage')
    time.sleep(5)
    return read
df = PeriodicDataFrame(random_datapoint, interval='300ms')
df
```

Output Should Be -

[image]

I don't understand How can I do this, I tried some [Code](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-conditional-formatting-in-pandas-8783035071ee) But these Codes aren't working with Live Streaming Code.

and this is my data

```
Instrument_token    Symbol  Datetime    Last_day_close  Last_trade_price(LTP)   Percentage  Bid_price   Ask_price
4   14246146    NIFTY22MAY17300CE   2022-05-04 13:30:35 230.05  173.00  -24.80  173.15  173.50
3   14245122    NIFTY22MAY17200CE   2022-05-04 13:30:35 276.45  210.50  -23.86  210.30  210.80
5   14241794    NIFTY22MAY17100CE   2022-05-04 13:30:35 331.00  254.20  -23.20  253.40  253.90
2   13468674    BANKNIFTY22MAY36000CE   2022-05-04 13:30:35 974.90  911.95  -6.46   910.00  912.50
1   12150530    BANKNIFTY22MAY29500PE   2022-05-04 13:29:22 11.05   11.00   -0.45   9.60    12.95
0   13467394    BANKNIFTY22MAY35900PE   2022-05-04 13:30:34 716.45  810.65  13.15   822.95  826.75
```

Comment: Please do no use images of code/data, provide a DataFrame constructor: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). We do not have access to you local files.

Comment: @mozway, Thank you for replying, I'm not getting your message completely, but I understand on the basis of that - I provide my code in text form.

Comment: and also the data as text ;)

Comment: @mozway okay. Got it.